# How do sequences restore their state on re-entry in Kotlin?

Tags: collections, kotlin, sequence

I wrote the following code, which appears to work

```
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.buildSequence

fun concatElemSeq(elem : String, seq : Sequence<String>) = buildSequence {
    seq.forEach { yield(elem+it) }
}

fun concatSeqSeq( seq1 : Sequence<String>, seq2 : Sequence<String> ) = buildSequence {
    seq1.forEach { yieldAll(concatElemSeq(it, seq2)) }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val seq = buildSequence {
        val l = listOf("A", "B", "C")
        l.forEach { yield(it) }
    }

    concatSeqSeq(seq, seq).forEach { println(it) }

}
```

Only one instance of `seq` is created and namely it is passed into functions, I checked in debugger. Nevertheless, code produces all combinations of charaters, which means, that it has copies of this sequence at various positions.

How is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I tried the same with `Iterator` and it didn't work. How to distinguish classes like `Sequence`, which restore their state, from classes like `Iterator`, which don't?

How to write my own class, which restores state on re-entry like `Sequence`?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're really asking. Sequences are potentially infinite, they can be iterated multiple times

Comment: The code effect can not be explained by just iterating multiple times.

Comment: @s1m0nw1, They can't necessarily be iterated multiple times. Simple counterexample: anything produced by `constrainOnce`.

Comment: @chris so once there is no such constraint, then how does it works?

Comment: Sequence is more like Iterable than Iterator. It even has iterator() method, which returns the iterator.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking there must be mutable state to restore in the first place. I'd say it's more akin to making a copy and operating on each copy. Except the copy in this case is a lightweight description (e.g., "I have a list {1, 2, 3}. Both copies start at 1.").

Comment: @chris how write my own class with such feature?

Comment: @asm0dey yes I agree; and if iterator contains position, then my code would have multiple clones of this iterator with different positions inside; but instance is always the same, I checked

Comment: Writing sequence behaviour is pretty involved, but coroutines can often simplify some things (and indeed, Kotlin uses coroutines under the hood). For example, a coroutine that yields 1, 2, and 3, is essentially a lazy sequence {1, 2, 3}, suspending after each value is yielded. Of course it's still possible to write sequences without using coroutines, but you have to pay attention to the lifetime of the data to produce. For example, C++ has range-v3, which bases its data on an underlying container, making the sequence a composition of functions to perform on each element when iterated.

Comment: The key thing in order to have this behaviour is to create a description of what's going to happen without actually having it happen. It's perfectly possible to copy that description and have each one iterate independently over the same data.

Answer (score 1):

Basically sequence is not iterator, it's more like Iterable.
It even has `iterator()` method inside, which can be defined in several ways - return one iterator or new instance on each call.